# Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'id') reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, graphql

I am building a blog in reactjs and graphql. I am trying to display posts made by specific authors by grabbing the id in the url and displaying posts through it but I keep getting an error message Please help, I have been battling with this for a while

Below are the code surrounding this error

**Error -** pages/author/[slug].jsx @ getStaticPaths

**Type Error:** Cannot read property of undefined (reading 'id')

services/index.js

```
export const getAuthorPosts = async (slug) => {
    const query = gql `
    query getAuthorPosts($slug: String!) {
        authors(where: {slug: $slug}) {
          bio
          name
          id
          photo {
            url
          }
          posts {
            createdAt
            slug
            title
            excerpt
            featuredImage {
              url
            }
          }
        }
      }
    `
    const results = await request(graphqlAPI, query, {slug})
    return results.authors
}
```

pages/author/[slug].jsx

```
import React, {useState, useEffect} from 'react'
import Link from 'next/link'
import { getAuthorPosts } from '../../services'

const AuthorPosts = () => {

  return (
    <div className="bg-white text-center shadow-lg rounded-lg p-8 mb-8">
      <h1 className="text-xl mb-8 font-semibold border-b pb-4">
      Author Posts
      </h1>
      <h4 className="text-sm border-b pb-4">{author.name}</h4>
      <div className="grid grid-cols-2 lg:grid-cols-4 gap-5 p-0 lg:p-4 pb-6 mb-8">
        {authors.map((author) => (
            <div className='bg-white rounded-lg shadow-xl'>
                <div className="relative overflow-hidden shadow-md mb-6">
                    <img 
                    src={author.photo.url} 
                    alt={author.name}
                    className="object-top h-full w-full rounded-t-lg"
                    /> 
                </div>
                <h3 className='transition duration-100 text-center mb-4 cursor-pointer hover:text-pink-600 text-2xl font-semibold'>
                <Link key={author.id} href={`/author/${author.id}`}>
                    {author.name}
                </Link>
                </h3>
                <p className="text-center text-lg text-gray-700 font-normal px-1 lg:px-2 mb-8">
                    {author.bio}
                </p>
                <div className="text-center mb-8">
                    <Link href={`/author/${author.slug}`}>
                    <span className="transition duration-500 transform hover:-translate-y-1 inline-block bg-pink-600 text-lg font-meduim rounded-full text-white px-8 py-3 cursor-pointer">
                        Continue Reading
                    </span>
                    </Link>
                </div>
            </div>
        ))}
      </div>
    </div>
  )
}

export default AuthorPosts

export async function getStaticPaths({params}) {
  const authors = await getAuthorPosts(params.id)

  return {
    props:{authors: data}
  }
}
```

components/author.jsx

```
import React, {useState, useEffect} from 'react'
import Link from 'next/link'
import { getAuthorProfile } from '../services'

const Authors = () => {
  const [authors, setAuthorProfile] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    getAuthorProfile()
      .then((newAuthors) =>setAuthorProfile(newAuthors))
  }, [])

  return (
    <div className="bg-white text-center shadow-lg rounded-lg p-8 mb-8">
      <h1 className="text-xl mb-8 font-semibold border-b pb-4">
      Authors
      </h1>
      <div className="grid grid-cols-2 lg:grid-cols-4 gap-5 p-0 lg:p-4 pb-6 mb-8">
        {authors.map((author) => (
            <div className='bg-white rounded-lg shadow-xl'>
                <div className="relative overflow-hidden shadow-md mb-6">
                    <img 
                    src={author.photo.url} 
                    alt={author.name}
                    className="object-top h-full w-full rounded-t-lg"
                    /> 
                </div>
                <h3 className='transition duration-100 text-center mb-4 cursor-pointer hover:text-pink-600 text-2xl font-semibold'>
                <Link key={author.id} href={`/author/${author.id}`}>
                    {author.name}
                </Link>
                </h3>
                <p className="text-center text-lg text-gray-700 font-normal px-1 lg:px-2 mb-8">
                    {author.bio}
                </p>
                <div className="text-center mb-8">
                    <Link href={`/author/${slug}`}>
                    <span className="transition duration-500 transform hover:-translate-y-1 inline-block bg-pink-600 text-lg font-meduim rounded-full text-white px-8 py-3 cursor-pointer">
                        View Posts
                    </span>
                    </Link>
                </div>
            </div>
        ))}
      </div>
    </div>
  )
}

export default Authors
```

Comment: Where is that error occurring? It could be when you're calling `getAuthorPosts` and params is undefined or the author data doesn't contain an id.

Comment: @Moath Hi, kindly review the question again as I've made some edits that likely answers your question, thanks. Also, the author contains an id but I can't tell if I'm calling it right

Comment: You're using `getStaticPaths` as if it were `getStaticProps`, `getStaticPaths` does not have a `params` parameter in its context. I'd recommend a read through https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/data-fetching/get-static-paths.